# Jquery get price by data-price attribute with each loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Actually I want to calculate price based on quantity. So I have a quantity field with id "input-quantity" and also I have defined discounts based on quantity. when I do on key up on quantity field an getting quantity value and also am getting discount price. but it is taking all the time discount price as 40 rs. but How I want is, if quantity is 10 more means price should be 50 and new price should be 10*50 = 500 and if quantity is 20 more means price should be 45 and new price should be 20*45 = 900 and if quantity is 30 more means price should be 40 and new price should be 30*40 = 1200. but is giving wrong results. How do resolve this.

Below is HTML,

```
    <div class="col-md-7 nopad pull-right">
                      <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" id="input-quantity" maxlength="3" class="form-control option-total" onkeyup="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"/>

                      <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
                      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
                    </div>

<?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
                  <!-- <h2 class="mT0 prodprice" class="prd-price" data-price="<?php echo $price; ?>"><?php echo $price; ?></h2> -->
                  <input type="hidden" data-quantity="<?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $discount['price']; ?>" class="disc-price">
                  <li><?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?><?php echo $text_discount; ?><?php echo $discount['price']; ?></li>
                <?php } ?>
```

Jquery code,

```
$("#input-quantity").on('keyup',function(){
  if($(this).val()=="" || $(this).val()==0){
    return false;
  }
  var total = $(this).val();
  // alert(total);return false;
  // $('#input-quantity').empty();

  var currency = $(".prodprice").text().match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)[0];
  var optprice = 0;
  // var actprice = $(".disc-price").data('price').match(/\d+/)[0];
  // alert(actprice);
  //var newprice = actprice;
  $(".disc-price").each(function(){
    var actprice = $(this).data('price').match(/\d+/)[0];
  // var total = $("#input-quantity").val();
    newprice = Number(parseInt(total)) * Number(actprice);
    newprice=commaSeparateNumber(newprice);
    $(".prodprice").text(currency+"."+newprice);
  });


});
```

Comment: better to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)